# Помогите решить проблему с кодировкой в python при записи в файл csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, unicode, cp1251

написал простенький парсер. Сохраняет данные в scv формат, кодировка обязательно cp1251 так как эти данные потом импортируются на сайт, а там принимает только в этой кодировке. Подскажите почему вылетает ошибка? причем вылетает рандомно, может пропарсить несколько страниц и выдать ошибку, а может и не одной не пропарсить и выдать ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manager\PycharmProjects\parser.py\main.py", line 124, in <module>
    parser()
  File "C:\Users\Manager\PycharmProjects\parser.py\main.py", line 118, in parser
    save_doc(info_list, CSV)
  File "C:\Users\Manager\PycharmProjects\parser.py\main.py", line 92, in save_doc
    writer.writerow(['', item['article'], item['title'], item['price'], '', 'СКАНЕРЫ ШТРИХ-КОДА',
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xba' in position 532: character maps to <undefined>
```

вот код, понимаю что он корявый, но это моя первая полноценная программа, прошу понимания.

```
import csv
import re
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

REG = r'([A-Z0-9]{3,}-[\w]{2}-[\w0-9]{3,})|([A-Z0-9]{3,}-[\w0-9]{3,})|([A-Z0-9]{3,}-[\w0-9]{2})'
HOST = 'https://interid.ru'
# URL = 'https://interid.ru/scanery-shtrih-kodov'
# CSV = 'scanner.csv'
# PARAMS = {'manufacturer_id': 13, 'param890': 648}
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
              'application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 '
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return req


# получаем url конкретной страницы продукта
def get_url(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    url = soup.find_all('div', class_='product')
    urls = []
    for i in url:
        urls.append({
            'url_page': HOST + i.find('div', class_='c-title').find('a').get('href')
        })
    return urls


# Собираем нужные данные с конкретной страницы продукта
def parser_page_product(html_page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')
    info_product = soup.find('div', class_='c-contents')
    info_product.encode('cp1251')
    params = []
    params_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='param')

    for i in params_list:
        params.append({
            i.find('div', class_='param-name').get_text(strip=True): i.find('div', class_='param-value').get_text(
                strip=True)
        })

    table_html = ''
    for i in params:
        for key, value in i.items():
            table_html = table_html + ('<tr><td>' + str(key) + '</td><td>' + str(value) + '</td></tr>')

    info_product_list = [{
        # название
        'title': info_product.find('h1', class_='c-header-product-title').find('span').get_text(strip=True),
        # артикул, полчаем через регулярное выражение
        'article': re.search(REG, info_product.find('h1', class_='c-header-product-title').find('span').get_text(
            strip=True))[0],
        # цена
        'price': info_product.find('div', class_='price').find('span', class_='price-value').get_text(strip=True),
        # ссылка на изображение
        'url_img': info_product.find('a', class_='c-images-list-item is-active').get('href'),
        # короткое описание
        'short_desc': info_product.find('div', class_='c-description').find('p').get_text(strip=True),

        # характеристики
        'params': '<table style="width: 65%;" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"><tbody>' + table_html +
                  '</tbody></table>'
    }]

    return info_product_list


# сохраняем данные в файл .csv
def save_doc(items, path):
    description = ' Заказ и доставка в течении 3 дней. Подбор, консультация, демо зал на Таманской.'
    title = ' купить в Краснодаре, оптимальная цена в магазине Штрих-Маркет'
    with open(path, 'w', encoding='cp1251', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['id', 'Артикул *', 'Название товара *', 'Стоимость товара *', 'Стоимость со скидкой',
                         'Раздел товара *', 'Товар в наличии *', 'Поставка под заказ *', 'Срок поставки (дни) *',
                         'Краткий текст', 'Текст полностью', 'Заголовок страницы (title)',
                         'Описание страницы (description)',
                         'Ключевые слова страницы (keywords)', 'ЧПУ страницы (slug)', 'С этим товаром покупают',
                         'Рекламные метки', 'Показывать на сайте *', 'Удалить *', 'Ед. измерения', 'Вес',
                         'Габариты, см',
                         'НДС', 'Передавать в Яндекс.Маркет'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow(['', item['article'], item['title'], item['price'], '', 'СКАНЕРЫ ШТРИХ-КОДА',
                             '0', '1', '15', item['short_desc'],
                             item['params'], item['title'] + title, item['short_desc'] + description, item['title'], '',
                             '', '', '1', '0', 'шт', '', '', '', '1'])


# основной метод
def parser():
    URL = 'https://interid.ru/scanery-shtrih-kodov'
    CSV = 'scanner.csv'
    PARAMS = {'manufacturer_id': 13, 'param890': 648}
    info_list = []
    html = get_html(URL, params=PARAMS)

    if html.status_code == 200:  # проверка статуса ответа сайта
        print('Сайт доступен!\nПарсинг запущен:')
        page = int(input('Укажите кол-во страниц для парсинга => ').strip())
        # проходим по страницам каталога и получаем ссылку на отдельную страницу каждого товара
        for page in range(1, page + 1):
            html = get_html(URL + '/page/' + str(page), params=PARAMS)
            print(f'Страница => {page}')
            # перебираем словарь; добавляем прогрессбар
            for i in tqdm(get_url(html.text)):
                for key in i:
                    html = get_html(i[key])
                    info_list.extend(parser_page_product(html.text))
                    save_doc(info_list, CSV)
        print('Парсинг окончен. Данные сохранены в файле ' + CSV)
    else:
        print('Ошибка! Неверная ссылка или сайт недоступен.')


parser()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать кодировку сохранения для CSV-файла и задать режим обработки символов, не входящих в множество кодировки cp1251:

```
def save_doc(items, path):
.....
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='cp1251', errors="ignore") as file:
        ....
```

Comment: А вы вопрос внимательно прочитали?

Comment: мне в кодировке cp1251 нужна. В utf-8 все прекрасно работает.

Comment: В тексте для сохранения встречаются символы, которые невозможно сохранить в кодировке cp1251. Поэтому нужно выбрать в open() подходящий параметр errors="" Например errors="ignore", если просто хотите игнорировать ошибки, будет пропускать такие символы. Выбрать параметр можно здесь: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: У меня файл сохранился вот таким образом: encoding='cp1251', errors="ignore"